# Embed a website utilizing javascript in new Google Sites

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, google-sites-2016

The following code loads several external js files and works great on my webserver:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/courses/hour-of-code/js/alphabet.js"></script>
<body>
    <div>
        <canvas id="myCanvas"></canvas>
        <script src="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=1lISKkEz4JTrPEFWKqpid-6sBByLP3wPY">
        </script>
        <script src="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=1lRAFdKQNu3YhBBDNEtj2WKDuLVM290pp">
        </script>
    </div>
</body>
```

Embedding this code in the new Google Sites produces a blank canvas.

To remedy, I created a webpage with only the javascript code running and attempted to embed it as an iframe in Google Sites using the following code:

```
<p align="center">
<iframe id="Bubbles"
    title="Bubbles"
    width="70%"
    height="250"
src="http://edtech2.boisestate.edu/joshuawatson/hiddenpage2.html">
</iframe>
</p>
```

This code runs fine on my webserver as well (as indicated by accessing the src page and seeing the working animation), but still yields a blank frame in the new Google Sites.

Any ideas on how I can make this script run on the new Google Sites?

Note that this is literally a "toy" example, the actual script I'm attempting to run is more complex and specific to my needs.

Answer (score 0):

I'll post the answer for the sake of anyone else who needs this, but it's not all that interesting.

The first issue is that some browsers (eg, Google Chrome) don't load unsafe scripts without explicit permission.

The second issue is that the server I initially posted refused iframe requests from other domains.

Hosting the page as an embedded iframe from Github pages solved both problems for me. I created an example Github page to demonstrate below:

Eg:

```
<p align="center">
<iframe id="Bubbles"
    title="Bubbles"
    width="70%"
    height="250"
src="https://uploadbakonbox.github.io/">
</iframe>
</p>
```